# Product Catalog

Tags: php

I am building a somewhat extensive product catalog for my father-in-law's business on his website.

I have experience with PHP, mostly procedural but I am now learning OOP. Knowing that, I am willing for this solution to be OOP.

I am trying to wrap my head around how to approach this. The database is not complicated. Each product is put into a Main category and Sub-Category, i.e. DVDs -> Action -> **Casino Royale**.

Does anyone know of a way that they have accomplished this and/or a tutorial that might help me with ideas on how to approach this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I truly appreciate the answers and have looked into many open source solutions, but here is what I'm looking for:

If someone has a best practice solution to a products portion of a website. I am not interested in building a strictly e-commerce site (nor am I entirely interested in taking the time to alter open-source to do what I need). This website has much more than just products, and that is not necessarily the focus. I am just looking to see if anyone has solved, either themselves or has found a good tutorial on displaying from a database of products the products themselves.

I hope I have not confused anyone. Thanks!

Comment: Do yourself a favor (and improve your relationship with your FIL) by not doing this from scratch.  There are probably many commercial and FOSS solutions for doing something like this.  Googling "php product catalog" turned up a number of tutorials and links to existing solutions.

Comment: Jason is right. I've another advice. If you want to build it from scratch (not a bad idea, just will take you more time) try a good MVC framework. I love CakePHP. There are "pluggable things" like "behaviors" that will help you acomplish your category/subcategory thing. If you'd like to start take a look at this book: http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-CakePHP-Professional-David-Golding/dp/1430209771/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1301444725&sr=8-1 Hope this help

Comment: to continue Jason's train of thought, these might be good to look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Open_Source_eCommerce_Software -- either to use directly, or if nothing else, to research how they solved the problems you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be all that difficult to create a database for something like what you want if it is a fairly simple product catalog. A produkt table, a category table and a table for attributes. Maybe several tables for attributes, depending on how you like to work..

Some SQL call to fetch the products and some html/css to display the products probably will not be a big hassle either.

What is left is doing a good search - or better - filtering the product when choosing category/attributes. That part probably could be quite time consuming. Look into a jQuery plugin to give the visitor the nice user experience.

If you then later want to extend with login and user rights to differentiate description/prices or just hide/show products, then you will regret that you didn't go for a framework (any odd CMS) with good user authentication, group rights etc. That also goes for mass upload or update of products, adding more languages and generally maintaining the site.

I would go for a framework.

Hint to your category and subcategory...

If you just stick to one category table then you can add a "parent" field to your category. If will in then that category is automatically a subcategory to the parent category. If you choose this as the category for your product it will automatically be given a main and sub category.

This approach is good since it supports categories in more than just two levels. You can go as deep as you want. And you can later move a hole brach of subcategories by just opdating the "parent" of a single node in the category tree. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is important to learn but if its time sensitive - you could find alternatives like Jason said.